# Import Git Reprository Library to Flutter

Tags: git, dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter an I have an issue to import Library to Flutter that hasn't been published in Pub. Here's the library that I want to import:
https://github.com/LiewJunTung/pin_code_text_field

And I've add this to my Pubspec.yaml as written in [Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages).

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  pin_code_text_field:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/LiewJunTung/pin_code_text_field.git
```

But I don't know how to import that to my current class. Usually if it's published in pub, you can easily put that as example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

But how if it's not? How to import that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  pin_code_text_field: ^1.2.1
```

And in your class you can import like this

`import 'package:pin_code_text_field/pin_code_text_field.dart';`

Comment: It imports from pub.dev